# Found an issue when use config file for my shell script

Tags: shell, configuration

configure.conf

```
fruit-list="apple, pear, banana, watermelon"
```

Script

```
source /configure.conf
```

Then it shows error:
/configure.conf: line 2: fruit-list=apple, pear, banana, watermelon: command not found

Can someone help me figure out why that happens?

I want the the fruit-list can be an list data type in shell script, which is same with

```
fruit-list="apple" "pear" "banana" "watermelon"
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (variable) name, at least with bash, may not contain a dash (`-`):

> name:  A word consisting only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and beginning  with  an  alphabetic character or an underscore.  Also referred to as an identifier. BASH(1)

You could use an underscore (`_`) instead:

```
fruit_list="apple, pear, banana, watermelon"
```

And if you want fruit_list to be array it would be:

```
fruit_list=(apple pear banana watermelon)
```

Comment: Thanks for figuring it out. It's a legacy code wrote by previous engineer so I will change it. Another question, is it a correct way to assign list with comma?

Comment: You should tag it with a specific shell.  There is no list type in bash.  Do you mean an array?  Then it's fruit_list=(apple pear ...).